# How to extract a field value from UnQLite collection

Tags: python, nosql, in-memory-database, unqlite

```
db = UnQLite('test.db')
data = db.collection('data')
print(data.fetch(0))
```

This prints

```
{'id': b'abc', 'type': b'business', 'state': b'AZ', 'latitude': 33.3482589, 
 'name': b"ABC Restaurant", 'full_address': b'1835 E ABC Rd, Ste C109, Phoenix, AZ 85284',
 'categories': [b'Restaurants', b'Buffets', b'Italian'],
 'open': True, 'stars': 4, 'city': b'Phoenix', 'neighborhoods': [], 
 '__id': 0, 'review_count': 122, 'longitude': -111.9088346}
```

**How do I fetch the value "Phoenix" for City?**

`type(data.fetch(0))` prints **class 'dict'**

I am looking at UnQlite documentation, not finding much. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already get a dict so you only need to search for the key

```
x = {'id': b'abc', 'type': b'business', 'state': b'AZ', 'latitude': 33.3482589, 
 'name': b"ABC Restaurant", 'full_address': b'1835 E ABC Rd, Ste C109, Phoenix, AZ 85284',
 'categories': [b'Restaurants', b'Buffets', b'Italian'],
 'open': True, 'stars': 4, 'city': b'Phoenix', 'neighborhoods': [], 
 '__id': 0, 'review_count': 122, 'longitude': -111.9088346}
x['city']
#b'Phoenix'
```

Here `Phoenix` is not a `str` object but `byte` so if you want it as string you can convert it by using `decode`

```
x['city'].decode()
#'Phoenix'
```

Or in your case:

```
data.fetch(0)['city'].decode()
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually I figured it's as easy as doing a get(). But, your answer is precise too. I like it better as it eliminates the 'b'

Comment: On another note, how do I iterate through the collection. Is there something called  size?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it. Doing a collection.fetch(0).get('city') gives the value.